# a question on spliting field

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Let $f$ be a polynomial of positive degree over a field $F$ and $E$ the spliting field of $f$ over  $F$ , do there exist
 some elements  $a_1,  a_2, ,…，a_s  $   of  $F$ and positive integers $n_1,n_2, ,…， n_s$  such that     $E=F(a_1^{1/n_1},a_2^{1/n_2},…，a_s^{1/n_s})$ ?

Comment: Not every normal extension is a radical extension.

Answer (score 0):

No that is not true. This follows by *Abel-Ruffini Theorem* (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem).

Comment: do there exist   
 some elements  $a_1,  a_2, ,…，a_s  $   of  $F$ and positive integers $n_1,n_2, ,…， n_s$  such that     $F(a_1^{1/n_1},a_2^{1/n_2},…，a_s^{1/n_s})$ contains $E$?